# redirection don't work correctly (Navigation)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, redirect, navigation

My component is in the record page of MyObj__c  .
MyObj__c  has a master detail with Account
I tried to navigate from MyObj__c to the account assorted bu I always get an error

```
Error : {"status":500,"body":{"message":"Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'MyId2' of type 'Id'"},"headers":{},"ok":false,"statusText":"Server Error","errorType":"fetchResponse"}
```

=> Apex

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Id Class2(Id MyId2) {
        Id account = [SELECT Station__c FROM MyObj__c WHERE Id =:MyId2 LIMIT 1]Station__c;
                   return  account;
    }
```

=> HTML

```
<template>  
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade">  
      <lightning-button label="Back to the station"  onclick={navigateToAccountPage}> </lightning-button>  
    </div>  
  </template>
```

=> JS

```
import { LightningElement, api , wire, track } from 'lwc';
import Class2 from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.Class2';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";

export default class RedirectToStation extends NavigationMixin (LightningElement) {
    @api recordId ;
    @track MyId2;
    navigateToAccountPage() {
        
        Class2({ MyId2: '$recordId' }).then(data => {

            if (data)
       {

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId :  data.Id,   
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'view'
                 }        });


       }
        
    }).catch(error => {

        console.log('Error : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    })

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code, please refer to the below code -

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    //pass the recordId as a string
    public static Id Class2(String MyId2) {
        Id account = [SELECT Station__c FROM MyObj__c WHERE Id =:MyId2 LIMIT 1].Station__c;
        return  account;
    }
```

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import Class2 from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.Class2';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
export default class RedirectToStation extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    navigateToAccountPage() {
        console.log('recordId', this.recordId);
        Class2({ MyId2: this.recordId }).then(data => {

            if (data) {
                // data is the recordId
                console.log('data', data);
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: data,
                        //objectApiName: 'Account',
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                });


            }

        }).catch(error => {

            console.log('Error : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        })

    }
}
```

You were passing the recordId in the wrong syntax. Removed the track variable MyId2.

Comment: thank you for your help , it worked for me